# Array.filter() is not removing the last item when a duplicate in the array exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers that when used with `.filter()`, the last item should be removed. The problem is whenever a duplicate exists, the method does not work.

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 2, 3, 4];
numbers.filter((num, index, array) => array.indexOf(num) !== array.length - 1)
```

Is there an easy way to fix this bug?

Comment: `indexOf` returns the first instance of the element, there is an alternative `lastIndexOf`, or a simple `numbers.pop()` should work.

Comment: I'm using React, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `index` instead of `array.indexOf(num)` maybe?

Or just mutate the array:

```
 numbers.pop();
```

Or if you want to get a new array:

```
 const withoutLast = numbers.slice(0, -1);
```

Comment: I'm using React, by the way.

Comment: @jstarnat that doesnt matter.

Comment: I used `.slice()`. Newbie here :)

Answer (score 1):

try `lastIndexOf` instead of `indexOf`

Either way, it's better to use other methods, as there are many!

1- `array.splice(-1)` removes the last element in the same array

2- `array.slice(0, -1)` removes the last element and returns a new array

3- `array.pop()` removes the last element in the same array